# How to get the number of queries which are executed per hour/day in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

Is there a way to get the number of Select/Update/Delete/Insert/Commit/Rollback queries that are executed in the last one hour or one day?

One way of doing this is by enabling the transaction logs and using Shell/Python tools to search for specific queries like this.

**cat postgresql-2022-02-25_105258.log | grep -i 'statement: select' | wc -l**
**28888**

The above command would fetch the number of select queries which ran and it is somehow helpful, but the problem with this approach is we cannot afford to restart a production server to enable the configuration setting **(logging_collector = on)**

Please do share if you are familiar with any other approach.

**Many Thanks,
Suresh.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While doing some reading on how to get the CRUD statistics I came to know about this procedure.

```
1) Enable the transaction logs in postgres by updating the configuration file
        log_min_duration_statement = 0
        log_line_prefix = '%t [%p]: user=%u,db=%d,app=%a,client=%h '
        log_checkpoints = on
        log_connections = on
        log_disconnections = on
        log_lock_waits = on
        log_temp_files = 0
        log_autovacuum_min_duration = 0
        log_error_verbosity = default
        logging_collector = on
        log_directory = '/var/postgreslog'
        log_filename = 'postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log'
        log_truncate_on_rotation = on
        log_rotation_age = 1d
        log_file_mode = 0600
2) Restart the postgres service
     /usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin/pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/11/main/ 
3) sudo yum install pgbadger --> if it's not existed on ur Linux box
4) /usr/bin/pgbadger -f /var/postgreslog/*.log --> **give the log file location, 
   in my case logs are there in /var/postgres**
[========================>] Parsed 544074587 bytes of 544074587 (100.00%), queries: 0, events: 0
LOG: Ok, generating html report...
5) The third step will generate an out.html file, open this HTML file from windows. it will give you a wonderful UI with the stats, we can feel the UI by going through the sample page
**https://pgbadger.darold.net/samplev7.html#slowest-individual-queries**
```